# Returning a 2D C array of type id in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, ios

I'm using a 2D C array of ids in my iOS app. Is it possible to return this in an objective-C method? As an alternative solution, I tried to return a pointer to a 2D C array of integers, but I cannot modify the 2D-int array.

```
- (int (*)[8][8])board:(Piece *)piece
{

    int (*layout)[8][8] = malloc(8 * 8 * sizeof(int));

    //Cannot modify layout 2D C array

    return layout;
}
```

I have some experience in Objective-C, but none in C. Am I likely to continually run into problems using C 2D arrays, such that I should make a 2D-Array Objective-C class? What is the more typical approach an iOS developer would use?

Comment: I always wonder how people can program in Obj-C without some C experience :) Try some C tutorial. It will help you understand Obj-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (int **)board:(Piece *)piece
{

    int **layout = malloc(8 * sizeof(int *));
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
       layout[i] = malloc(8 * sizeof(int));


    return layout;
}
```

Don't forget to free the memory in the end. Also, you could also use a one dimensional array and something like this to access it in a similar way:

```
#define access(array, x, y) array[y * 8 + x]
```

There is also now drop in multi-dimensional array class in Objective-C, but you could create a `NSArray` with other `NSArray`'s inside of it, or, google if someone else did this (I remember at least one implementation but can't recall its name)

Answer (score 0):

After you declare `int (*layout)[8][8] = malloc(8 * 8 * sizeof(int));`, You can change the values like `(*layout)[x][y]=val;`. But I recommend you to declare `int (*layout)[8]`, so you can access elements by simply `layout[x][y]=val`.

Edit: I don't know about Objective-C, but in C, the function I suggested will look like:

```
int (*newarray())[8] {
 int (*l)[8]=malloc(64*sizeof(int));
 // You can do stuff like l[2][4]=15 here
 return l;
}
```