# 2D Array Returning Method in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, methods

I am trying to make a simple test function that works with 2D arrays. The aim would be to process the 2D array, increase every integer by 1, then return the 2D array.

However I have some trouble with the method declaration. I have tried this so far:

```
//this is the part that does not work
-(int[][])incrementBoard:(int[][])board{

...

}
```

However this gives an error. The return type should be of type int[][], and it should be able to handle an input of an int[][] array.

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329914/returning-a-2d-c-array-of-type-id-in-objective-c) question, bit I still cannot find out how declare this function.

Thank you in advance,

**Edit**

The function now works. However, when I try to pass a 2D array, it crashes thread 1 bad access, and the message, `incompatible pointer types passing int[8][8] to parameter of type int**`

How can I edit the function so it accepts arrays of type int[][]?

Comment: Can you add the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is a little late but I thought I should post the working answer:

```
int incrementBoard(int board[][8]){

}
```

So a method that can take a 2D array (lets say of integers, for example) looks like:

```
int function(int array[][])
```

which is similar to admin's answer as in it is a C function, just with the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Try using true c function instead of obj- c method.
i. e. use

```
int** incrementBoard(int** board, i, j /*array length*/){}
```

instead of

```
-(int **)incrementBoard:(int **)board{}
```

It should solve your problem.

**UPDATE**

If you know array size at compile time you could use instead

```
int[8][8] incrementBoard(int[8][8] board){}
```

Comment: And how could I change the array inside e.g. do board[1][1] = 7; crashes with thread one bad access

Comment: @parkgatedev if there's a bad access error, that's because the array wasn't allocated, so be sure to use allocating function.

Comment: I have deduced that int[][] and int** are different types and it can't handle the types, but I was wondering how I could use the function you proposed to handle int[][] types.

Comment: The warning message that shows is "Incompatible pointer types passing int[8][8]  to parameter of type int**" I have declared the array as int set[8][8];

Comment: @parkgatedev    int set[8][8];
   incrementBoard( set, 8, 8); should do the trick

Comment: It still doesn't work. Are you sure that int[][] is compatible with the function which is int**? This is the error that I am still getting at the moment.